# MPVolumeView is working only for iPod

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad

I have added MPVolumeview like this in my project

Here is my code used for iPad.

-(void) addVolumeControl
{

```
volumeView = [[MPVolumeView alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake(780, 33, 150, 40)];


NSArray *tempArray = volumeView.subviews;

for (id current in tempArray)
{
    if ([current isKindOfClass:[UISlider class]])
    {
        UISlider *tempSlider = (UISlider *) current;
        [tempSlider setMaximumTrackTintColor:[UIColor clearColor]];

        CGRect rRect = tempSlider.frame;
        rRect.origin.x = rRect.origin.x + 20;
        tempSlider.frame = rRect;

        UIImage *pMaxTrackImage;
        UIImage *pMinTrackImage;
        UIImage *pThumbImage;

        pMaxTrackImage = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"pgbar_sound_fill_ipad"]resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 6, 0, 6)];
        pMinTrackImage = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"pgbar_sound_bg_ipad"]resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 6, 0, 6)];
        pThumbImage    = [UIImage imageNamed:@"pgbar_sound_thumb_ipad"];

        [tempSlider setMaximumTrackImage:pMaxTrackImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [tempSlider setMinimumTrackImage:pMinTrackImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [tempSlider setThumbImage:pThumbImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }
}

volumeView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin;

[self._bottomBar addSubview:volumeView];
```

}

Volume is working fine while running application in iPod, but it is not working in iPhone and iPad.

The devices I tested are iPod5 and iPhone5C.
And Operating systems I tested are iOS6 and iOS7.

I have tried almost all the helps available, none worked for me.
Please provide some suggestions/guidance.

Thanks,

Nikhil.T

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set theses values `setMinimumTrackImage`, `setMaximumTrackImage`, `setThumbImage`

```
for (UIView *sv in [volumeSlider subviews])
{
    if ([sv isKindOfClass:[UISlider class]])
    {
        UISlider *slider = (UISlider*) sv;
        [slider setMinimumTrackImage:yourImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [slider setMaximumTrackImage:yourImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [slider setThumbImage:yourImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank u very much for your reply; I have tried this, but it is not working for iPhone and iPad. I didn't integrated any code for playing video or any video yet. I am still working on my own library for playing video. Is that a reason for this, do i need to use something related to media playing or something related to that to get enable this for iPad and iPhone? Because it seems volume view is not enabled in iPad and iPhone in my application.

Comment: `MPVolumeView *volumeView` should be iVar variable

Comment: Okay, I have edited my question(pasted code used for iPad), still not working for iPhone and iPad :(

Comment: I used above code and it works (show MPVolumeView). Let double check X-Position you set for MPVolumeView

Comment: I was able to see MPVolume but it is not getting adjusted with volume button in iPad/iPhone. But it is getting adjusted with iPod. I know this irritating, I am sorry. Thank u so much for your support.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why it is not working in iPad and iPhone. But I think the right way to set left track and right track image is by using the following methods.

Now I am using the following methods in my code, hope this helps someone

> MPVolumeView *pVolumeView = [[MPVolumeView alloc] initWithFrame:myFrame];
>
> [volumeView setMaximumVolumeSliderImage:myImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
> [volumeView setMinimumVolumeSliderImage:myImage
> forState:UIControlStateNormal];
> [volumeView
> setVolumeThumbImage:thumbImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];